# Reading Digits/Integer from File in Java

Tags: java, arrays, io

I am trying to count all integers from a file but I keep getting error because of this `.toCharArray();` and `.length()`; they're both "it cannot find symbol - method toCharArray()"?

```
public static void main(String[] args){  
        try{
            FileReader f = new FileReader(("numbers.txt")); //replace this to exact location where you store numbers.txt in computer
            Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

            char[] count = input.toCharArray();
            int num = 0;
            for (int i =0;  i<input.length(); i++){
                if(Character.isDigit(count[i])){
                    num++;
                }
                System.out.println("There are "+num+" numbers in the file.");
            }
            } catch(Exception s){
            System.out.println(s.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

numbers.txt:

```
8 96 54 25 
104 19 
112 86 73 
16 30 112 57 
2 26 64 83 
65 
36 1 
25 
18 111 
56 104 8 36 87
```

My expected output like this:

```
> There are 28 numbers in the file.
```

Comment: `Scanner input` - now go and read the javadocs for `Scanner`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I just check your input file. Your approach which is to count every digit is completely wrong. YOu have to split the line to array of words by `white space` and check whether that word is number.

---

You can read your file by `FileInputStream` and process it line by line. Each line will split to words by `white space` if you wanna count only numbers (with multiple digits) or you can convert a line to array of chars and check each character.

Here are two classes that you need to use `FileInputStream` and `BufferReader`.

The example is based on your code (counting digits)

```
// Open the file
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

String line = null;
int count = 0;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
   for(Character c: line.toCharArray()) {
      //check if the c is a digit and increase count
   }
}
 //Close the input stream
 fstream.close();

//return count or print it out.
```